# Materialize CSS - Collapsible

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm working with Materialize CSS and using the collapsible accordion-style element ( http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html ).

For some reason, as soon as I click to open an item, it immediately closes.

Here is my code.  My goal is simply to be able to use collapsible as intended (i.e. with the element opening and remaining open).

```
<div style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">

    <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
        <li>
        <% latestTweet = CLIENT.user_timeline(friend.twitterHandle)[0] %>
          <div class="collapsible-header">

            <img src="<%= latestTweet.user.profile_image_url %>" width="40" height="40"><%= link_to friend.firstName + " (" + friend.twitterHandle + ")", "friends/" + friend.id.to_s  %><div style="float:right"><%= (Indico.sentiment(latestTweet.text)*100).round %></div>
          </div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p>
                <%= latestTweet.text %>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because **Materialize** requires **JQuery 2.1.1** while Rails uses **1.11.2.**

In your **assests/application.js** try

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
```

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
<div id="accordian">
<div style="width:600px; MARGIN:0 auto;">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">

    <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
        <li>
        <% latestTweet = CLIENT.user_timeline(friend.twitterHandle)[0] %>
          <div class="collapsible-header">

            <img src="<%= latestTweet.user.profile_image_url %>" width="40" height="40"><%= link_to friend.firstName + " (" + friend.twitterHandle + ")", "friends/" + friend.id.to_s  %><div style="float:right"><%= (Indico.sentiment(latestTweet.text)*100).round %></div>
          </div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p>
                <%= latestTweet.text %>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out their documentation at:http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/